# Run time Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set when showing userform

Tags: excel, runtime-error, userform, vba

I have problem with closing one userform and going to next. UserForm3 after clicking command button should be closed and UserForm4 should be shown. Unfortunately I get "Run time Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set". I've dug deep into internet and I am pretty sure that problem is with Userform4, although code for UserForm3 is highlighted as bugged. Basicly I want UserForm4 to be displayed and have all the textboxes filled with data from sheet "Log", based on choice from Combobox from UserForm3. Choice from UserForm3 is saved to cell E1 on "Log" Sheet.

**Code from UserForm3**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Log").Range("E1") = ComboBox2.Text
Unload Me
UserForm4.Show  <- ERROR DISPLAYED HERE

End Sub
```

In `UserForm4` I want to find value from E1 in cells below and later on fill textboxes in Userform4 with data from the row, in which E1 value was found.

**Code for UserForm4**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Name As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wart As Worksheet

wart = Sheets("Log").Range("E1")
LastRow = ws.Range("B3" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Name = Sheets("Log").Range("E1")
UserForm4.TextBox8.Text = Name

nazw = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wart, Sheets("Log").Range("B3:H" & LastRow), 1, False)

UserForm4.TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox4.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox5.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.ComboBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox6.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
UserForm4.TextBox7.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `wart = Sheets("Log").Range("E1")`  ?? Is `wart` a `Worksheet` object or `Range` object ? If it's worksheet, then `Set wart = Sheets("Log")` . If it's a `Range`, then  `Set wart = Sheets("Log").Range("E1")`.

Comment: I want "wart" to be the contents of "E1" cell. Later on it should be searched with Vlookup.

Comment: then change your `Dim wart As Worksheet` to `Dim wart As String` if "E1" contains a string, or `Dim wart As Integer` (or `Long`) if E1" contains a Number. You could also use `Dim wart As Variant`

Comment: Ok i changed it to `Dim wart As String`. Now i get "Compile Error: Object required"  with `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` highlighted in yellow and `Set wart = ` in blue.

Comment: where is `ws` set and declared ?

Comment: all code I posted is in UserForm4. `Set ws = Sheets("Log")` is declared in UserForm1 though.

Comment: add 2 lines, `Dim ws as Worksheet` to declare the `ws` as worksheet object. Second, you need to set the `ws` to a worksheet, use `Set ws = Sheets("Log")`, if you want to use "Log" sheets. Then, in LastRow, use `LastRow = ws.Range("B3" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Ok I did what you asked, but i still get "Compile Error: Object required" with `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` highlighted in yellow and `Set wart =`  in blue.

Comment: i'll write some code below, to get rid of the errors I know so far. let me know if they resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is to avoid to run-time errors mentioned in the code above, it's not debugged for the `VLookup` function part.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Name        As String
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim wart        As Variant
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim nazw        As Long

' set ws to "Log" sheets
Set ws = Sheets("Log")

With ws
    wart = .Range("E1")

    ' method 1: find last row in Column "B" , finds last row even if there empty rows in the middle
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' method 2 to find last row, equivalent to Ctrl + Shift + Down
    ' LastRow = .Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

    ' a little redundant with the line 2 above ?
    Name = .Range("E1")
End With

With Me
    .TextBox8.Text = Name

    ' ****** Need to use Match instead of Vlookup VLookup Section ******
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(wart, ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow - 1), 0)) Then
        nazw = Application.Match(wart, ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow - 1), 0)
    Else ' wart record not found in range
        MsgBox "Value in Sheet " & ws.Name & " in Range E1 not found in Column B !", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .TextBox1.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox2.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox3.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox4.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox5.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .ComboBox1.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox6.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
    .TextBox7.Text = ws.Range("B" & nazw).Offset(, 1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: All good now, apart from Vlookup part you mentioned. Answering you question about `ActiveCell`. I thought that once Vlookup is used (eg. value found in cell B4, that is my active cell.

Comment: Do you know how can I "explain" to excel that I want my ActiveCell to be the cell in which "wart" is found?

Comment: @Igor yes, using the `Match` instead of `VLookup` . In which column in "Log" sheet so we need to search for `wart` ?

Comment: wart should be found in column B

Comment: @Igor then please mark my answer with a **V** , and add another post with your needs, and your current code.

Comment: It works perfectly! YOU ARE GREAT! Now I just need to create "save" button so the table is updated with changes entered by user in UserForm4 in correct row. Any ideas? I tried to copy crucial parts of what you already posted, but I it doesnt paste updated contents of textboxes into worksheet. Any ideas?

Comment: @Igor thanks :) the way SO works, your question in your post was answered. Now, you should open a new post, put your updated code, describe there what you are trying to do, and where are you getting your error. It will allow other user's here also to help you

Comment: OK I will. You really helped me a lot already :)  Link to new thread: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011500/saving-data-from-userform-to-worksheet-issue>